# Why can't ProcessBuilder find a file created in an earlier process?

Tags: java, msbuild, processbuilder

My code first compiles a C# program by calling ***msbuild***, and then run the newly created exe.
The code successfully compiles the  program, and I can see the newly created files, but the next process can't find them.
It keeps throwing a `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "path-to-my-app\bin\Debug\App.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

If I run one at a time, each one works successfully, but not together.

Here is the method that runs msbuild:

```
    public App compileApp() throws IOException {
        String[] param = new String[5];
        param[0] = "msbuild";
        param[1] = "-clp:ErrorsOnly;verbosity:minimal";
        param[2] = "-fl";
        param[3] = System.getenv("WORKSPACE") + "\\App.sln";
        param[4] = "-p:Configuration=Debug";
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(param);
        pb.redirectError(new File("App error.txt"));
        pb.start();
```

And here I run the app:

```
public App runApp (String executionChoice) throws IOException{
        Process p;
        String line;
        String[] param = new String[2];
        param[0] = System.getenv("EXE_PATH");
        param[1] = executionChoice;
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(param);
        pb.redirectError(new File("App error.txt"));
        try {
            p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while((line = input.readLine()) != null){
                logger.info(line);
            }
            input.close();
            p.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }finally {
            assertAll(null, test);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

My guess is, that the sub processes did not finish by the time the 2nd method was called, and that's why it can't find the file. Here is what I tried already but did not work:

1. Calling p.waitFor() - for some reason doing this prevented the exe from being created altogether, the bin and Debug folders were created, but not the exe.
2. Hard sleep wait - completely ineffective.
3. Running the compilation part as a batch file instead, like Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path-to-my-.bat") - This rendered the same results

Comment: `path-to-my-app` <- did you replace it when pasting here, or is it what you're actually using? Is it valid path?

Comment: @MirekPluta I replaced it, the path is valid, I double checked by copying it to file explorer and opened the app.